# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar un registro con php para un PDF?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, dompdf

Tengo esta página por partes las cuales me genera un PDF al presionar un botón

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" onclick="location.href='../Dreporte.php'">Descargar reporte</button>
```

Ese es el botón que tengo en una página A, y me envía a este código que es en otra página B.

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$usuario = "root";
$password = "root";
$servidor = "localhost";
$basededatos = "prueba";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password) or die ("No se ha podido conectar");

$db = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos) or die ("Error con la BD");
$codigoHTML='


<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title> ReportePDF
    </title>
</head>

<body oncontextmenu="return false">

        <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><center>
                    REPORTE EJEMPLO PDF
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="red">
                <td><strong>id</strong></td>
                <td><strong>nombre</strong></td>
                <td><strong>fecha</strong></td>
            </tr>';

                $consul = "SELECT * FROM ptabla";

                $sql=mysqli_query($conexion, $consul);
                while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                    $codigoHTML.='
                        <tr>
                            <td>'.$res['id'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$res['nombre'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$res['fecha'].'</td>
                        </tr>';
                }
            $codigoHTML.='
        </table>
</body> </html>';

 $codigoHTML=utf8_encode($codigoHTML);
 $dompdf=new DOMPDF();
 $dompdf->load_html($codigoHTML);
 ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
 $dompdf->render();
 $dompdf->stream("Reporte_user.pdf");     ?>
```

Y sí me genera el PDF

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero yo lo que necesito no es que me tome todos los registros de la tabla 'ptabla', sino que solo tome uno y se muestre en el PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facil, cuando pulses el botón tendras que pasarle a tu script un id

```
$id = $POST['idMostrar'];
```

Luego simplemente basta con filtrar en tu consulta por ese id.

```
$consul = "SELECT * FROM ptabla where id = $idMostrar";
```

Asi quedaría tu código.

```
<?php
 //Parte 1
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$usuario = "root";
$password = "root";
$servidor = "localhost";
$basededatos = "prueba";

$id = $POST['idMostrar'];

//Sentencia de la conexión a la base de datos

$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");

$db = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos) or die ("Error con la BD");
$codigoHTML='


<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title> ReportePDF
    </title>
</head>

<body oncontextmenu="return false">

        <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><center>
                    REPORTE EJEMPLO PDF
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="red">
                <td><strong>id</strong></td>
                <td><strong>nombre</strong></td>
                <td><strong>fecha</strong></td>
            </tr>';

                //Parte 2

                $consul = "SELECT * FROM ptabla where id = $idMostrar";

                $sql=mysqli_query($conexion, $consul);
                while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                    $codigoHTML.='
                        <tr>
                            <td>'.$res['id'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$res['nombre'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$res['fecha'].'</td>
                        </tr>';
                }
            $codigoHTML.='
        </table>
</body> </html>';

//Parte 3
 $codigoHTML=utf8_encode($codigoHTML);
 $dompdf=new DOMPDF();
 $dompdf->load_html($codigoHTML);
 ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
 $dompdf->render();
 $dompdf->stream("Reporte_user.pdf");     ?>
```

Adicionalmente, es mejor que uses consultas preparadas para evitar inyecciones SQL. Para. [Aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) tienes un ejemplo de como funcionan.

Comment: intenté hacerlo como mencionaste, pero sencillamente no me salió :c intenté igual hacer algo similar como en otras preguntas similares, pero tampoco

Comment: ¿Que parte no te fundiona?

Comment: Pues porque intenté hacerlo con la recomendación que me diste, pero no parece haber funcionado, simplemente me deja el pdf como algo "no legible" es decir, con errores o que está dañado; intenté pasarle el id al botón, pero no

Comment: Vale, ya se que es, cambia `$id = $POST['idMostrar'];` por `$idMostrar = $POST['idMostrar'];`

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo hacer la primera parte? Es decir, pasarle un script con la id en el botón, tengo entendido que lo puedo hacer con $_GET, pero francamente no encuentro cómo

Comment: Tal como lo tienes tendrias que poner `onclick="location.href='../Dreporte.php`?id=x' donde x es el id necesario. Luego si lo recogerias con $_GET en vez de $_POST

Comment: Hasta ahora lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera este es el del botón `<input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" onClick="location.href='../Dreporte.php?id=<?php $_GET["id"]; ?>'" value="Descargar reporte">` y se supone que lo estoy recibiendo como `$id = $_GET['id']; ` y en la consulta donde lo filtro queda con  `SELECT * FROM ptabla where id = $id"; ` y sí me genera el pdf, pero lo hace como no legible, ¿Lo estoy pasando mal?

Comment: Depende, que vale `$_GET["id"]` en el `onclick()`

Comment: Ya lo eh conseguido, en realidad su respuesta me ha ayudado y sólo tuve que hacer un var_domp($id) en otro archivo para ver sí me enviaba el id... muchas gracias por su ayuda, en verdad se lo agradezco